# How to fix "raise ImportError("Need hypothesis>=3.58 to run tests")" for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm having trouble importing pandas onto my Jupyter notebook as I keep getting `NameError: name 'pd' is not defined`. While double checking other sources, I believe this has led me to think that pandas might be the problem.

What do I need to update or change? I upgraded my Python to the most current version as well.

Here's my terminal code to test:

````
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> pd.test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_tester.py", line 16, in test
    import hypothesis  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hypothesis'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_tester.py", line 18, in test
    raise ImportError("Need hypothesis>=3.58 to run tests")
ImportError: Need hypothesis>=3.58 to run tests```
````

Comment: What happens when you type `pd.__version__`?

Comment: Your error says something different than _pd is not defined_. I'm not sure what `pd.test()` is supposed to do, but I'd say you need the `hypothesis` package to let it work.

Comment: @Scott-Boston It prints '0.25.1'

Comment: Your pandas appears be installed.  Can you create an complete example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing Hypothesis, try "conda install Hypothesis" to make pd.test() work. That made the test work for me.